# Angular2 hash location without folder directory structure

Tags: angular

I am developing product with Angualr2 Beta.

I hope to change location policy.

I want THE URL be like

> localhost/**app.html#location1**

(I think alpha version was like above)

NOT

> localhost/**app.html/#/location1**

By `provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})`

NOT

> localhost/**app.html/location1**

By `provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: PathLocationStrategy})`

Because the case not for me requires web-server settings. but I don't want to put extra work. and I it's enough for me to be able to just bookmark hash style routing.

If you have an idea about it. please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom `LocationStrategy`.  Here is an adapted version of `HashLocationStrategy` to suit your needs.

The `prepareExternalUrl()` method is where I made the changes.  I'm sure there is a way to stop Angular 2 from removing the html filename from the URL, but as a quick workaround I have added it back in using the `prepareExternalUrl()` method.

It is worth noting that configuring the URLs in this way stops deep linking from working on the initial page load.  Subsequent navigation works as expected.

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Optional, platform } from 'angular2/core';
import { LocationStrategy, PlatformLocation, APP_BASE_HREF } from 'angular2/router';
import { joinWithSlash, normalizeQueryParams } from 'angular2/src/router/location_strategy';
import { UrlChangeListener } from 'angular2/src/router/platform_location';
import { isPresent } from 'angular2/src/facade/lang';

@Injectable()
export class CustomHashLocationStrategy extends LocationStrategy {
    private _baseHref: string = '';
    constructor(private _platformLocation: PlatformLocation,
        @Optional() @Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) _baseHref?: string) {
        super();
        if (isPresent(_baseHref)) {
            this._baseHref = _baseHref;
        }
    }

    onPopState(fn: UrlChangeListener): void {
        this._platformLocation.onPopState(fn);
        this._platformLocation.onHashChange(fn);
    }

    getBaseHref(): string { return this._baseHref; }

    path(): string {
        // the hash value is always prefixed with a `#`
        // and if it is empty then it will stay empty
        var path = this._platformLocation.hash;

        // Dart will complain if a call to substring is
        // executed with a position value that extends the
        // length of string.
        return (path.length > 0 ? path.substring(1) : path) +
            normalizeQueryParams(this._platformLocation.search);
    }

    prepareExternalUrl(internal: string): string {
        var url = joinWithSlash(this._baseHref, internal);
        return url.length > 0 ? ('app.html#' + url.substring(1)) : url;
    }

    pushState(state: any, title: string, path: string, queryParams: string) {
        var url = this.prepareExternalUrl(path + normalizeQueryParams(queryParams));
        if (url.length == 0) {
            url = this._platformLocation.pathname;
        }
        this._platformLocation.pushState(state, title, url);
    }

    replaceState(state: any, title: string, path: string, queryParams: string) {
        var url = this.prepareExternalUrl(path + normalizeQueryParams(queryParams));
        if (url.length == 0) {
            url = this._platformLocation.pathname;
        }
        this._platformLocation.replaceState(state, title, url);
    }

    forward(): void { this._platformLocation.forward(); }

    back(): void { this._platformLocation.back(); }
}
```

Comment: thank you for a quick answer.
I learned directive designing as well by your source.

and put addiction information about routing.
I use also react framework for other products(because it is stable). react router module allows to use bookmark style hash location which i wanted. so If there are some who looking forward using this function. you can consider using react also.(even not so heavy to transfer from angular2 to react)

thanks!